# how to hide dive on mouse click $(document).click will hide when I show the index page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have index page it should show my div with id myajaxdiv how to hide it when a user click n every where in the page? this code will hide it even in index page without any click.

```
$(document).click(function() {
   $("#myajaxdiv").css({'display':'none'});
});
```

my div is empty and with ajax I will make it full
html:

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav">
          <div id="myajaxdiv" >           
            </div>
```

and in ready function I have ajax:

```
$.ajax({

        type:'POST',
        url:'news.php',
        success:function(data){
            var query ='';
    var mycontent = 'تازه ها<hr/>';
        $('.queryForm').hide(300);
    $('.message').html('');

    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

                    query = data[i];
                    mycontent += '<ul class="starred-queries"><li class="question">' + query.ques  + '</li>';
                    mycontent +=  '<li class="answer">' + query.answer + '</ul>';                   

            }

            $('#myajaxdiv, .well #myajaxdiv').html(mycontent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm either super tired, or your wording is pretty hard to understand. Try re-phase the question.

Comment: have you done on click `<a href="javascript:void(0)">` ?

Comment: yes, try this change in yout HTML and follow NullPointer's answer

Comment: @ViralShah I forgot that I had void in my links.that's not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.button').click(function() {
$("#myajaxdiv").css('display','none');
}) });
```

Comment: It doesn't have any difference

Comment: I tried it with some class it's weird that I should have write another ready function besides my another one Thanks buddy  I mean I had ready function full code but when I added another it is now working

Answer (score 1):

To hide the div when an element is clicked, you could do the following (ie. for class button):

```
$('.button').click(function() {
   $('#myajaxdiv').hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
     $("#myajaxdiv").hide();

})
```

Comment: I tried it before,unfortunately it will hide it again from scratch

Comment: something weird is here this will hide my other divs too even from the first without clicking something wrong is here

Comment: @nikparsa  its only possible that you have same id for the other div, are you using the same id for other div ?

Comment: Nope I don't have the same ID for example if I try your code by $('a').click it will again hide my div but just the one with id myajaxdiv

Comment: @donvoters check the first line of the question he wants to hide the div on click anywhere